# Horizontal line doesn't show up in Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In my Activity_main.xml file I have added few lines of code for a horizontal line but when I run the emulator it does not show up.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textAppearance="@style/Divider"
android:showDividers="middle"/>

Styles.xml
<style name="Divider">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
<item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>
```

It does not show any errors? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no need of orientation for textview which you have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your approach,

Replace

```
    <TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textAppearance="@style/Divider"
android:showDividers="middle"/>
```

With

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use a `TextView`. You can simply use a `View`

In your layout file:

```
<View style="@style/HRLine">
```

In your style file:

```
<style name="HRLine">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/yourLineColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have used this line at the end <View style="@style/Divider"/>. I tried your code but it's still not working

Comment: If the answer helped you fix your problem then Mark it as accepted answer.